# Symmetric Difference of a Triplet of Sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am doing set theory out of interest and am stuck on the following question:

Show that:

**Z \ (X Δ Y) = [Z \ (X  ∪ Y)]  ∪ ( X  ∩ Y  ∩ Z)**

My approach:

Beginning with the RHS:

[Z \ (X  ∪ Y)]  ∪ ( X  ∩ Y  ∩ Z)

==> [Z ∩ comp.(X  ∪ Y)]  ∪ ( X  ∩ Y  ∩ Z)

==> [Z ∩ (comp.X ∩ comp.Y)]  ∪ ( X  ∩ Y  ∩ Z)

This is where I get stuck. I can use Demorgan's Laws to take the Z out so to speak, and am left with the following:

==> Z ∩ [(comp.X ∩ comp.Y)  ∪ ( X  ∩ Y )]

Which is nowhere near the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Completed Solution thanks to the user Graham Kemp below:

==>  [(comp.X ∩ comp.Y)  ∪ ( X  ∩ Y )]

==> (comp.X ∪ Y) ∩ (X ∪ comp.Y)

==> comp.[(X ∪ comp.Y) ∪ (comp.X ∪ Y)]

==> comp.(X Δ Y)

Plugging in gives solution required.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this I didn't know of this result. Would upvote if I could!

Answer (score 1):

Next use distributution, and identity laws:  $$\require{cancel}(X^c\cap Y^c)\cup(X\cap Y) = \cancel{(X^c\cup X)\cap}(X^c\cup Y)\cap(Y^c\cup X)\cancel{\cap(Y^c\cup Y)}
\\ = ((X\cap Y^c)\cup(Y\cap X^c))^c$$